# I'm using Energia IDE; I'm trying to upload a sketch to my board but I get this error

Tags: arduino

Energia: 1.8.11E23 (Windows 10), Board: "MSP-EXP430FR2433LP"

```
Global variables use 20 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 4076 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 4096 bytes.
DSLite version 9.3.0.1863
Configuring Debugger (may take a few minutes on first launch)...
Failed: Cannot read System Setup data from XML file C:\Users\rbeta\AppData\Local\Energia15\packages\energia\tools\dslite\9.3.0.1863/MSP-EXP430FR2433LP.ccxml
Error parsing file:
Fatal Error at (0, 0): An exception occurred! Type:RuntimeException, Message:The primary document entity could not be opened. Id=C:\Users\rbeta\AppData\Local\Energia15\packages\energia\tools\dslite\9.3.0.1863/MSP-EXP430FR2433LP.ccxml
Fatal Error at (0, 0): An exception occurred! Type:RuntimeException, Message:The primary document entity could not be opened. Id=C:\Users\rbeta\AppData\Local\Energia15\packages\energia\tools\dslite\9.3.0.1863/MSP-EXP430FR2433LP.ccxml

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Seems related to some sort of prior [update problem](https://github.com/platformio/platform-timsp430/issues/14). As discussed, the problem was solved by using a correct ccxml file. Yours could be [here](https://github.com/energia/msp430-lg-core/tree/master/variants/MSP-EXP430FR2433LP)